# Remote deployment of a web app to Geronimo using Cargo or geronimo-maven-plugin?

Tags: geronimo, maven-cargo

I am a maven beginner.. and geronimo for that matter.  I'm trying to figure out how to deploy webApp war file to a remote geronimo server so I can set up a continous integration environment.

Let me elaborate:

- system A has Eclipse maven project and no geronimo installed .
- system B have an geronimo server

now I want  to execute maven goals from system A for a war file of my webApp to be built then remotely deployed (probably would need to undeploy an existing one first) on System B. 
I've been reading up on Cargo and the "geronimo-maven-plugin " and its way over my head.  There is a lot of examples of remote deployment with cargo to tomcat, but that's not going to work for me.

Any suggestions on where to begin to solve the above scenario would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!